# I am working on an Quiz game i am trying to get user input from the player in ters of button by adding listeners

Tags: unity, c#

but i get no touch input when i make click on gameplay, i have added onClick().Here is the code......................

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Level2UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<string> sceneHistory = new List<string>();
    [SerializeField] private Level2Manager gameManager;
   [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI questionText;
   [SerializeField] private List<Button> options;
   [SerializeField] private Color CorrColor, WrongColor, NormalColor;
    private Question question;
    private bool answered;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    
    void Awake()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
        {   
            Button localBtn = options[i];
            options[i].GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ClickedAnswer(localBtn); });
            //   localBtn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ClickedAnswer(localBtn); });
            Debug.Log("testclick");
      //      btn.onClick.AddListener(ClickedAnswer);
            
        }
    }
    public void SetQuestion(Question question)
    {
        this.question = question;
        questionText.text = question.questionInfo;
     
        List<string> answerList = ShuffleList.ShuffleListItems<string>(question.options);
        for(int i=0; i< options.Count; i++)
        {
            options[i].GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = answerList[i];
            Debug.Log("check");
            options[i].name = answerList[i];
            options[i].image.color = NormalColor;
        }
        answered = false;
   //     setButton();
    }

    public void ClickedAnswer(Button btn)
    {
       
        print("txt");
        if (!answered)
        {
            answered = true;
            bool val = gameManager.Answer(btn.name);

            if (val)
            {
                btn.image.color = CorrColor;
                Debug.Log("test1");
            }
            else
            {
                btn.image.color = WrongColor;
                Debug.Log("test");
            }
        }
    }
    //Call this whenever you want to load a new scene
    //It will add the new scene to the sceneHistory listss
    public void LoadScene(string newScene)
    {
        sceneHistory.Add(newScene);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(newScene);
    }

    //Call this whenever you want to load the previous scene
    //It will remove the current scene from the history and then load the new last scene in the history
    //It will return false if we have not moved between scenes enough to have stored a previous scene in the history
    public bool PreviousScene()
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        if (sceneHistory.Count >= 2)  //Checking that we have actually switched scenes enough to go back to a previous scene
        {
            returnValue = true;
            sceneHistory.RemoveAt(sceneHistory.Count - 1);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneHistory[sceneHistory.Count - 1]);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you ever calling your SetQuestion method? In the code provided you do not and SetQuestion is adding your listener at the end.

Comment: i am calling setquestion in another script

Comment: It doesn't look like we have enough information here to reproduce the problem. Please boil this down to a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: list every step we would need to follow, starting from a blank, empty project, to build a scene that shows this problem. Once we can do that, we can use it to test potential solutions.

Comment: I have added question and answer to come randomly using different script. In this method i am try to get the input from the player using button.

Comment: i have updated the script

Comment: Can you confirm whether Zibelas's minimal example in the answer below works for you, when you try it out in a new scene? If it does, you can add functionality from your script/scene into Zibelas's minimal example, testing after each small addition. If the problem arises again, then you know the last thing you added triggered the problem, and that can help you narrow down the cause.

Answer (score -1):

I reduced your project to the smallest running example.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Demo : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] private Button option;

void Awake()
{
    option.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ClickedAnswer(option); });
}

public void ClickedAnswer(Button btn)
{
    Debug.Log("button clicked");
}

}
```

Which is working and prints button clicked when clicked. This is tested on an empty scene with nothing but a canvas, the auto added event system and a single button on the canvas.

Since this code sample is not working for you and in your screenshot you are missing the event system as well. This should be the reason why your clicks are failing. Normally it gets automatically added to the scene when you first add the canvas. If by chance you deleted it or it is othervise missing, you can just add it again from GameObject - UI - Event System.

Comment: But how does this answer the question? "Works on my machine" is not really helpful if you can not tell why it doesn't work for the question author.

Comment: This is not a works on my machine but a full workable code made from what the op asked with just reduced lines. The posted code is still missing code like the question class. If the bare minimum is running for him, he can just add more lines until he finds out when it is not running anymore

Comment: i have tried this but not working,i will update my code above

Comment: @DeepuPrakash Did you include the eventsystem or better, could you provide a screenshot from your scene?

Comment: @Zibelas, i have added the screenshot, you want the screenshot of code

Comment: @DeepuPrakash in your screenshot you are missing the eventsystem that gets added automatically when you first add a canvas to your scene. Which is as well most likely the source why it is not working for you.

Comment: @Zibelas thank you so much that was the issue, eventsystem was missing.Now its workfile.